# Nested network requests with RxJava

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, observable, rx-java2

I'm very new to RxJava. I have a problem with converting a nested async operation into RxJava structure. Having a single async task that fetches data from the server has not been a problem to create, however I do have a problem with an exemplary case of this sort:

```
List<A> aaa = new ArrayList<>();
List<B> bbb = new ArrayList<>();

new FetchItemA(String id){
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<A> items){
      foreach(A item:items){
          new FetchItemB(item.getId())
              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(List<B> newItems){
                 neededList.addAll(newItems);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

}

The problem is with the return types. I've created my observable this way:

```
Observable.fromArray(String userId)
      .map(new Function(String, List<A>){
          @Override
          public List<A> apply(String id){
             return getListA();
          }
      })
      .map(new Function<String, List<B>){
          @Override
          public List<B> apply(String id){
              someList.add(getItemB(id));
              return someList;
          }
      })
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(new Observer(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<B> items){
               bbb.addAll(items);
               adapter.setItems(bbb);
            }
      });
```

This however is illegal as this `Observable`expects the type `List<A>`whereas I'm returning `List<B>`. How can I structure my RxJava observable to be able to fetch a list of items (of type A, each having a unique id), and based on the fetched list, fetch a single item (of type B) with id (of each item of type A in the first list) as the argument, and only after add the received items (of type B) to a list?

Answer (score 0):

The essential step in fetching the data is to transform each `A` into a `B` using a network call. In the RxJava world, that means wrapping the network call in an observable and then using the `flatMap()` operator.

```
Observable.fromList(aaa)
  .flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<B>>() {
     @Override
     public Observable<B> call(A a) {
       return Observable.fromCallable(getNetworkValueAsB(item));
     }
   } )
  .toList()
  .subscribe( new Observer<List<B>>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(B bItemList) {
      bbb.addAll(bItemList);
      adapter.setItems(bbb);
    }
    });
```

The operations are `fromList()` which converts from the `List<A>` to `Observable<A>`, `flatMap()` which converts from `A` to `B` using the call, and `toList()` which gathers all the `B` values produced into a list, which is then used in the subscription.

The `fromList()` operator might be called `fromIterable()` or `from()` depending on the version of the library you are using.

Edited to removed lambdas

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Im using rxandroid:2.0.1 and rxjava:2.1.3. Therefore I will need to call fromIterable(). How would I define the body of flatMap without using lambdas? I tried using retrolambda library, but even then android studio would complain that "lambda operations are not supported on this language level".

Comment: constructing a new `Observer` and overriding the `onNext()` method will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand correctly. `Observer` is passed to `subscribe()`, whereas `flatMap` needs a `Function` (or `Func1` in older version of the library). If I call `flatmap` like: `.flatMap(new Function<List<A>, List<B>>` I will have the IDE complain about return types being wrong. Unless I'm completely mistaken here?